# Hide a div if the header tag within it is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a carousel where I am trying to hide the description for certain slides if no content is being output dynamically.

My structure with content being output:

```
<div class="caption">
   <h3><a>title</a></h3>
   <p><a>description</a></p>
</div>
```

My structure without:

```
<div class="caption">
   <h3><a></a></h3>
   <p><a></a></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if($.trim($('.caption h3 a').text()) != "") {
$(".carousel-caption.h").addClass("visible");
}
```

I got the javascript from looking through similar questions on here. I have tried various ways of doing this but to no avail. I am not quite sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this to hide all `.caption` having an empty header :

```
$('.caption').show().filter(function(){
   return $.trim($('h3', this).text())===''
}).hide();
```

This might be nearer from your initial solution, changing only the class when the head has a content :

```
$('.caption').each(function(){
    if ($.trim($('h3', this).text())!=='') $(this).addClass('visible');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a jQuery guy. But in YUI it can be simply like:

```
if (Y.one(".caption h3 a").get("innerHTML") == "") {
    alert("its empty");
}
```

try using .html instead of .text in jquery

Answer (score 0):

this works,

```
 if($('.caption h3 a').text().trim() != "") {
       $(".carousel-caption.h").addClass("visible");
 }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KfCZ/)